# kABPersonRelatedNamesProperty

Tags: iphone

I find the Apple documentation extensive but I also find guidance on the syntax for code lacking in explanation or examples.

Is there any reference books/documents on coding the address book in general and for my specifics the Related Name Property in the ABPeoplePickerNavigationController Class available?

Answer (score 1):

Just for information to people who is searching the same term and looking for simple example:

```
ABMultiValueRef relatedNames = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonRelatedNamesProperty);
NSMutableArray *relatedNameList = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];

for(CFIndex j = 0; j < ABMultiValueGetCount(relatedNames); j++) 
{
    NSString *relatedNameLabel = [(NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(relatedNames, j) autorelease];
    if (relatedNameLabel == nil) 
    {
        relatedNameLabel = @"";
    }
    NSString *relatedNameString = [(NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(relatedNames, j) autorelease];
    if (relatedNameString == nil) 
    {
        relatedNameString = @"";
    }
    NSArray *relatedNameArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: relatedNameLabel, relatedNameString, nil];
    [relatedNameList addObject:relatedNameArray];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Look at that -

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/userexperience/Conceptual/AddressBook/AddressBook.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000117i